# How to make the animation on a website where a piece of text changes every seconds?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, web

It's like the animation they have on npm front page and also on the brown hackathon page. Where a piece of  text erases and appears every few seconds with different content. I think There may be an existing template for it online, but what do they call it?

Comment: Any effort from your side??????

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to get started..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basic idea how to create this kind of animation check following snippet:

> If you want to expend this animation just add letters in array.

```js
$(function() {
 var arr = ['t','te','tex','text','G','Go','Goo','Goog','Googl','Googl','Google'];
  var elem = $('#ani');
  var i = 0;
  var loop = function(){
   elem.text(arr[i++]);
    if(i>arr.length) {
     //clearInterval(intervalID);
        i=0;
      }
  }
  
  var intervalID = setInterval(loop, 500);
})
```

```css
.test{
  font-size:26px;
  color:green;
}
.ani{
  color:red;
}
.ani::after{
  content:"|";
  -webkit-animation: cursor-blink 0.8s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: cursor-blink 0.8s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: cursor-blink 0.8s linear infinite;
  animation: cursor-blink 0.8s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes cursor-blink {
  1% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cursor-blink {
  1% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes cursor-blink {
  1% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes cursor-blink {
  1% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  This is text 
  <span class="ani" id="ani">
   Google
  </span>
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Will it work if the background of that page is a video?

Comment: One more thing, what do i need to do with the .js snippet if i want to start over after all the text in the array is displayed?

Comment: Sure you can do this. See updated answer it will repeat array to infinity.

Comment: when i applied the updated code and ran a test the video background stops responding as well as the array. I have about 150 items in the bracket and when I reduced the number of items in the array everything's running again. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Check in console may be you are getting any Compile time error.

Comment: found issue. My computer was too slow it crashes when there's too many items